# What if I have several questions associated with one topic?

Tags: support, questions, etiquette

If I have a question based on a specific topic (e.g. a special suit) and I have several questions associated with this topic (e.g. how it works, where it will work, and how effective it is), is it better to separate the question into several questions, or list all of the questions under one? Is there some sort of etiquette on how this is done?

Answer (score 5):

### One question per question

To make things easier to answer, you should only put one question in each WB question you ask.  That helps keep you focused and all the people who might answer focused too.  If you do include more than one question per question, it will likely be closed as "too broad".

Link each previous question in your new question so that people can get a sense of the context you are working with.  Off-handedly, there's this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20664/naturally-occurring-wheels-do-the-mech-vs-tank-comparison-apply-to-organi) that references a previous question on a topic.  Something similar should work for your needs.

As Monica said, make sure each question is self-contained.  Links to other question should be for context only, not important information required to answer the question.

Comment: Links to past questions are fine (I've [done that too](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/25318/28)), but make sure each question is self-contained.  People shouldn't have to follow the links to understand your question, though the links can provide additional context.

Answer (score 3):

**One question per *Question***, *several questions over a longer time*

As the format is intended for questions with a single clear answer (and we're already stretching that on here..), the best way to go about in my opinion & experience is to *ask several questions*.

As your questions will most likely be interwoven you should start by asking one thing and then do follow-ups using decisions made based on (the) answer(s) you've received on (the) previous question(s).

*exempli gratia*: My excellent series of questions on the mean booze-rat:

1. [On how the booze-rat would store alcohol in its body](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56710/how-does-the-booze-rat-fuel-its-defensive-mechanism)
2. [Then on how that system could possibly evolve](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56945/how-did-the-booze-rat-evolve-its-defensive-mechanism)
3. [And eventually on how to milk <s>the hype</s> booze-rat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/58096/how-do-the-people-of-hj%C3%A5rdan-farm-the-booze-rat)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers:
Please make sure that people who are following the question see that the solution gets more and more detailed and developed whenever an answer is incorporated in the new question. dot_Sp0T's example is a good one.

**"Several questions associated with one topic" should not mean that you *ask the same question over and over and change only the conditions* because you are not satisfied with the given answers.**

This happens when answers to both questions would achieve the same effect.
Example:

Q: "I want to crack a safe with a campfire".
A: "Not possible. Use a thermal lance."
Q: "I am cracking a safe with a campfire. The campfire uses coal".
A: "Still not hot enough. *Use a thermal lance*".
Q: "I want to open a safe with campfire. The door is only 1mm thick".
A: ...