# Is it a nuisance to ask multiple questions on one subject?

Tags: discussion, questions

I’m building a creature and have needed to conceive locomotion, aerodynamics, structural design and other reality-based features. I have done this through several different questions, in an iterative piecemeal process which [seems to be the prescribed method](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/what-if-i-have-several-questions-associated-with-one-topic) of solving large problems.

However as the pieces come together there seems to be a declining interest trend leading to fewer and fewer views and responses to questions. It feels like the topic is possibly wearing on users - even though each question is a unique challenge.

I’m not blaming anyone, and maybe it just needs more time. This is just how things appear at this time. This is somewhat preemptive.

## Are multiple questions on one development a nuisance with diminishing returns?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, since you didn't link any of the subject questions, is each question requiring more detail or source knowledge than the one before to answer? Or do they use different tags and, thus, are aimed at different interests?

Comment: Part of the issue is at least that questions you are asking are both technical and on quite difficult subjects. Your lastest question is pretty specialised. None of these things help. I'd also note that inactive questions get pushed off the front page by newer questions by other people, which makes them even less likely to be answered soon. Maybe consider spacing the questions about a bit?

Answer (score 5):

## NO: Technically Not a Nuisance

This is how SE is designed. You formulate a focused query; we formulate a focused answer; you choose which one works best for you.

Obviously, if you try to formulate a single query with locomotion, aerodynamics, and structural design components, it'll be shut down pretty quick for being too broad.  And we won't be afraid to tell you that ought to know better by now! ;)

Sadly, I think your line of questioning *may be* suffering from diminishing interest.  It's also possible that people are thinking that, after all the initial help given, perhaps it's time you took on more and more of the work yourself.  It's also possible that people are beginning to think you're lacking creativity: why are you asking *so many questions* about a single topic rather than sorting out issues on your own.

I hold that you are following best practice by compartmentalising a complex problem into distinct sub-problems.  You might consider taking what help has been given so far and try to sort some issues out on your own.  You might also consider letting that problem rest for a while.  Work on something else and come back to it later.  But ultimately, I think you're going to fight something of an uphill battle against human nature: people might be getting bored of the same sub-problem within a larger project.